# C# fill an access database from a dataset

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, dataset

I have a program which is supposed to open, edit, create and save access databases. For saving I copy an empty database with just the tables (just to avoid going through the hassle of creating every table  and column etc) and try to fill it with values via the TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll method.

```
string _TemplateConnectString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};";
_connection = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(_TemplateConnectString, dlg.FileName));
_connection.Open();

DataSet1TableAdapters.TableAdapterManager tam=new TableAdapterManager();
tam.Connection = _connection;
try
{
    tam.UpdateAll(dataset);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Update failed");
}
```

It finishes with no exceptions but the values don't get inserted into the new database.

Also as far as I know the UpdateAll method only updates modified row so if I open some db and it inserts it's rows, it will not take them into account even though there are not in the database that I am trying to fill.

I have also tried filling the database with the ADODB and ADOX extensions but all the solutions I found with those was a lot of hardcoding and no regards for hierarchy, keys, etc.

Is there a way to force insert everything in the new database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clumsy solution but it works. I iterate the tables of the dataset and save the via an sql string generator like this:

```
void SaveTable(DataTable dt)
    {
        string[] inserts;
        try
        {
            inserts = SqlHelper.GenerateInserts(dt, null, null, null);

            foreach (string s in inserts)
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = s;
                cmd.Connection = _connection;
                int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SaveOk = false;
        }
    }
```

I found the SqlHelper somewhere on this site, but completely lost where, unforunately. So here is the pastebin with it https://pastebin.com/iCMVuYyu

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the right Data source database name, here an 
example with an excel file:

```
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
       "Data Source=c:\somepath\ExcelFile.xls;" & _
       "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
```

Comment: But it is right. The data source is the database that I open. The connection opens fine with the open status. It is the next part that has a problem

Comment: May you insert for example only a single sample data, not the whole dataset?

Answer (score -1):

Is your template database in the Visual Studio project directory? It might have something to do with Visual Studio copying the database to the bin/debug or bin/release folder...

Comment: Looks like a comment to me, not like an answer.

Comment: Yes I have an emptydb.mdb file with all the preset but empty tables. I do not allow to save in that file thought. Only to databases with different names